# ¿Cómo conservar los eventos tras modificar el nodo?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una serie de procesos por los cuales se modifica el contenido de la etiqueta `<html>` a través de Javascript

Por lo que he podido comprobar, al modificar el nodo de dicha etiqueta en el DOM, se pierden los eventos que se han añadido anteriormente, lo que quisiera hacer es mantener los eventos tras hacer cualquier modificación en el nodo

Lo que intenté es guardar una variable global que sea un array de objetos, en la cual cada objeto tendría una estructura así

```
el: <Nodo>
n: <nombre del evento, ejemplo "click">
v: <función callback a ejecutarse cuando se cumpla el evento>
```

El problema, es que al modificar el `<html>` se cambian las entidades de los nodos, haciendo que el nodo que guardé deje de existir en el documento actual

Esta es la implementación que tengo

```js
if (!window["eventsConfiguration"]) window["eventsConfiguration"] = [];

eventsConfiguration.push({el:reverse,n:"click",v:(() => {
    msg.innerHTML = msg.innerHTML.split("").reverse().join("");
})});
  
reverse.addEventListener("click", () => {
  msg.innerHTML = msg.innerHTML.split("").reverse().join("");
});

document.querySelector("html").innerHTML+="";
// ...

console.log(eventsConfiguration);
console.log(document.body.contains(eventsConfiguration[0].el));
// false
```

```html
<p id="msg">Hello</p>
<button id="reverse">Reverse</button>
```

Esta solo es una prueba con un elemento, en realidad estoy trabajando con todos los elementos del DOM que tengan un atributo específico y guardar un objeto por cada uno en el array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No había tomado nota de ese `.innerHTML +=` y resulta que cada que modificas el contenido de esa forma, el navegador debe volver a interpretar todo el código del contenedor y por eso es que se pierden las referencias. Creo que ya se había comentado en otras preguntas o respuestas.

La solución es muy simple, usa [.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) para agregar nuevo contenido y creo que debería ser en el cuerpo del documento, no en `<html>`.

```js
if (!window["eventsConfiguration"]) window["eventsConfiguration"] = [];

eventsConfiguration.push({el:reverse,n:"click",v:(() => {
    msg.innerHTML = msg.innerHTML.split("").reverse().join("");
})});
  
reverse.addEventListener("click", () => {
  msg.innerHTML = msg.innerHTML.split("").reverse().join("");
});

document.querySelector("html").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Más texto');
// ...

console.log(eventsConfiguration);
console.log(document.body.contains(eventsConfiguration[0].el)); // true
```

```html
<p id="msg">Hello</p>
<button id="reverse">Reverse</button>
```